# Give a word for momentarily touching something repeatedly

Tags: single-word-requests

I have an application to write where a tree is touching an electric wire. Please suggest a suitable word.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the word 'tap'.

This is how the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tap) defines it:

> **Tap:** To hit something gently, and often repeatedly, especially making short, sharp noises.
>
> Example: The branches tapped against the window.

Answer (score 3):

*Brushing* is the word.

Due to the wind the tree's branch kept *Brushing* against the power line. The consequences could be easily anticipated and much dreaded. I find no dictionary definition takes into consideration the physical conditions involved since the conditions do not change during the storm until the disaster.

The repeated Brushing of the branch on the power line is what causes the eventual problem.

Comment: That's precise!

Comment: I thought of this as an answer — I rather liked it — but I couldn’t find any applicable dictionary definition that conveyed *repeatedly*. Prove me wrong by adding a dictionary definition.

Comment: @RichardKayser The present participle strongly implies repetition for any action that takes a very short period of time to complete. If something only takes a second, for instance, the present participle would normally not be used to describe it—because it would be over in the time it took to describe it.

Comment: @JasonBassford Note that the answer uses the work *kept*. Also, which dictionary definition would you use?

Answer (score 1):

Trees *sway* in the wind, and when near electrical lines, they can **beat** those lines like waves beat the shore. From M-W:

> [*sway*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sway): the action or an instance of swaying or of being swayed : an oscillating, fluctuating, or sweeping motion

> **[beat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beat)**: to strike directly against forcefully and repeatedly

The oscillatory motion of a *swaying* tree could cause it to **beat** a nearby  electrical line, i.e., to strike directly against it forcefully and repeatedly.

Comment: *Sway* doesn't imply any contact. (Also, "the oscillatory swaying"?)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the comments. I've revised the answer.

Comment: As a musician I can certainly vote for *beat*.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks. That means a lot, given your well-developed critical faculties here on ELU. What kind of musician?

Answer (score 0):

the branch "flapped" against/on the wire?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is **click**:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> 1 : to strike, move, or produce with a click
> // *clicked* his heels together

Using the present participle conveys the sense of repetition:

> She heard the tree branches *clicking* against the electrical wire.

Comment: A tree branch striking an electric wire is more likely to produce a muted sound; Click, on the other hand, is a sharp sound.

Comment: @Stockfish Perhaps, but it also depends on context. There would certainly be a lot of sharp sounds occurring between tree branches and electrical wires during an ice storm, for instance.

Comment: "clicking" refers to a bistable system rapidly transitioning to a different stable state.

Comment: @Acccumulation Is that what I do when I click my mouse button, click my fingers against my table, or click my tongue against the roof of my mouth?